# One page only by content

Tags: xsl-fo

Please, how to do in xsl-fo something as receipt printing? It means only one page printout with height of page by content? So far, I have only working with A4 printouts with paging, now I need to print a long receipt, ie a single-page long printout, where I do not know the length of the page. Thanks.

Comment: What do you use to print the receipt?

Comment: Hi Jirin, I'm using xsl-fo of apache FOP to print bill/receipt and have the same issue as you, did you find a way to calculate the actual length of the content?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in two passes:

- Format the receipt on a very long page
- Get the area tree of the formatted receipt to find the height of the content
- Format again using a page of the desired height

XSL-FO, as implemented, really only works with fixed page heights. XSL 1.1 allows you to use `page-height="indefinite"` (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#page-height), but AFAIK, it isn't implemented by any formatter.

Every formatter (I believe) can output an XML representation of its formatted result. Area Tree XML is formatter-specific, but you may be able to use the XSLT Extensions from the Print and Page Layout Community Group (see https://www.w3.org/community/ppl/wiki/XSLTExtensions and https://github.com/pplcg/XSLTExtensions) both to simplify working with the Area Tree XML and to do it within your XSLT transformation.

Once you know how much space the receipt needs, you can regenerate/modify the XSL-FO to use a page of the correct height to fit everything exactly.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, what you write sounds logical. So if I understood it correctly, on the XSL side, the output would be a document that would have a very long height of page, and finding out the actual length of the content and resetting the correct page length would have to be provided by the processor, right? So for me, Apache FOP. Am I right?

Comment: See https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.7/running.html. You would write the XSLT to generate XSL-FO for a very long page height. Run that through FOP using the `-at` or `-if` option (I can never remember which one is the useful one) to generate an XML representation of the formatted document. Examine that to find the actual height needed for the receipt (i.e., write some XSLT to extract the required height from the XML representation). Either re-run the original XSLT with the desired page height or modify the XML representation to use the desired page height and feed that back into FOP.

Comment: Hi Tony, how could I _"Get the area tree of the formatted receipt to find the height of the content"_ as you suggest?

Comment: @kieuanhvu, use the `-at` or `-if` command-line parameters as in my previous comment.

Comment: Hi @TonyGraham, if using cmd-line parameters I must run **FOP** as **Standalone Application**. May I use Apache FOP classes  (exp: org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent, org.apache.fop.apps.Fop, org.apache.fop.fo.FOTreeBuilder, or something) in my code to calculate the content height?

Comment: @kieuanhvu: I don't know. I use and prefer Antenna House Formatter. I answer FOP questions, when I can, just to help out XSL-FO users, but most of what I know about FOP comes straight from the FOP webpages. Since you are comfortable with Java code, you might look at the FOP code in the XSLT Extensions from the Print and Page Layout Community Group (see https://github.com/pplcg/XSLTExtensions/tree/master/src/org/w3c/ppl/xslt/ext/fop), which embeds FOP as an extension to different XSLT processors to make the Area Tree available to XSLT code.